.NET MAUI Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type
When I start the App it crashes with exception: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type. Error is occured on the initial screen. This is the whole log that i get:
**System.ArgumentException:** 'Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.'

**System.ArgumentException:** 'Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.'

[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] Unhandled Exception from source=AppDomain
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Type target, String method, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Type target, String method)
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Android.Runtime.AndroidTypeManager.RegisterNativeMembers(JniType nativeClass, Type type, ReadOnlySpan`1 methods) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/AndroidRuntime.cs:line 557
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.Object.AllocObject(JniObjectReference type) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 20911
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Java.Interop.JniType.AllocObject() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniType.cs:line 196
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance(String constructorSignature, Type declaringType, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.cs:line 139
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView..ctor(Context context) in C:\a\_work\1\s\generated\androidx.appcompat.appcompat\obj\Release
et6.0-android\generated\src\AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView.cs:line 51
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiTextView..ctor(Context context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\MauiTextView.cs:line 9
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LabelHandler.CreatePlatformView() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Label\LabelHandler.Android.cs:line 10
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILabel, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnCreatePlatformView() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 72
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.OnCreatePlatformElement() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandler.cs:line 184
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.CreatePlatformElement() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 101
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 50
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILabel, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 53
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILabel, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.UpdateContent() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Android\FrameRenderer.cs:line 354
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.<>c.<.cctor>b__73_6(FrameRenderer h, Frame _) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Android\FrameRenderer.cs:line 28
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 172
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 47
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 82
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.VisualElementRenderer`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view, IPlatformViewHandler nativeViewHandler, Action`1 onElementChanged, Frame& currentVirtualView, IPropertyMapper& _mapper, IPropertyMapper _defaultMapper, Boolean autoPackage) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\VisualElementRenderer.cs:line 290
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ViewHandlerDelegator`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view, Action`1 onElementChanged, Boolean autoPackage) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\ViewHandlerDelegator.cs:line 84
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.Microsoft.Maui.IElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Android\FrameRenderer.cs:line 405
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Layout\LayoutHandler.Android.cs:line 41
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 42
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 47
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 172
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 47
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 82
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 79
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 53
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 26
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiContextExtensions.ToPlatform(IView view, IMauiContext fragmentMauiContext, Context context, LayoutInflater layoutInflater, FragmentManager childFragmentManager) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\MauiContextExtensions.cs:line 96
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellFragmentContainer.OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Shell\Android\ShellFragmentContainer.cs:line 26
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_inflater, IntPtr native_container, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) in C:\a\_work\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release
et6.0-android\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:line 2031
[AppCenterXamarinCrashes]    at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L(_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0, IntPtr p1, IntPtr p2) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 367
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
[mono-rt]    at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Type target, String method, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
[mono-rt]    at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Type target, String method)
[mono-rt]    at Android.Runtime.AndroidTypeManager.RegisterNativeMembers(JniType nativeClass, Type type, ReadOnlySpan`1 methods) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/AndroidRuntime.cs:line 557
[mono-rt] --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
[mono-rt]    at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.Object.AllocObject(JniObjectReference type) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 20911
[mono-rt]    at Java.Interop.JniType.AllocObject() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniType.cs:line 196
[mono-rt]    at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance(String constructorSignature, Type declaringType, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.cs:line 139
[mono-rt]    at AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView..ctor(Context context) in C:\a\_work\1\s\generated\androidx.appcompat.appcompat\obj\Release
et6.0-android\generated\src\AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView.cs:line 51
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiTextView..ctor(Context context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\MauiTextView.cs:line 9
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LabelHandler.CreatePlatformView() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Label\LabelHandler.Android.cs:line 10
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILabel, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnCreatePlatformView() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 72
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler.OnCreatePlatformElement() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandler.cs:line 184
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.CreatePlatformElement() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 101
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 50
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILabel, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 53
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILabel, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.AppCompatTextView, Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.UpdateContent() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Android\FrameRenderer.cs:line 354
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.<>c.<.cctor>b__73_6(FrameRenderer h, Frame _) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Android\FrameRenderer.cs:line 28
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 172
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 47
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 82
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.VisualElementRenderer`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view, IPlatformViewHandler nativeViewHandler, Action`1 onElementChanged, Frame& currentVirtualView, IPropertyMapper& _mapper, IPropertyMapper _defaultMapper, Boolean autoPackage) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\VisualElementRenderer.cs:line 290
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ViewHandlerDelegator`1[[Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Frame, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view, Action`1 onElementChanged, Boolean autoPackage) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\ViewHandlerDelegator.cs:line 84
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer.Microsoft.Maui.IElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Android\FrameRenderer.cs:line 405
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.LayoutHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Layout\LayoutHandler.Android.cs:line 41
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.UpdateContent(IContentViewHandler handler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 42
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.MapContent(IContentViewHandler handler, IContentView page) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 47
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.<>c__DisplayClass5_0[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IContentViewHandler, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].<Add>b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 172
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 47
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperties(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\PropertyMapper.cs:line 82
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Element\ElementHandler.cs:line 79
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 53
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ContentViewHandler.SetVirtualView(IView view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\ContentView\ContentViewHandler.Android.cs:line 26
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].SetVirtualView(IElement view) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\View\ViewHandlerOfT.cs:line 56
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 921
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element\Element.cs:line 863
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IElement.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\VisualElement\VisualElement.cs:line 2031
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToHandler(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 96
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ElementExtensions.ToPlatform(IElement view, IMauiContext context) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\ElementExtensions.cs:line 127
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiContextExtensions.ToPlatform(IView view, IMauiContext fragmentMauiContext, Context context, LayoutInflater layoutInflater, FragmentManager childFragmentManager) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\MauiContextExtensions.cs:line 96
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellFragmentContainer.OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Compatibility\Handlers\Shell\Android\ShellFragmentContainer.cs:line 26
[mono-rt]    at AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.n_OnCreateView_Landroid_view_LayoutInflater_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_Landroid_os_Bundle_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_inflater, IntPtr native_container, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) in C:\a\_work\1\s\generated\androidx.fragment.fragment\obj\Release
et6.0-android\generated\src\AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment.cs:line 2031
[mono-rt]    at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L(_JniMarshal_PPLLL_L callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0, IntPtr p1, IntPtr p2) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 367

Does anyone got a same problem? I don't know where to search for the crash...
P.S The app works on iOS

That looks like an invalid binding in some user control. Have you any custom controls in the app?

@PMF after days of searching I just changed build from bundle to apk and that solved my problem. But I want to know the reason why this happend...

Well, according to your comment, as a wiki answer:

When I start the App it crashes with exception: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

Changing build from bundle to apk can avoid the problem for now.
About bundle and apk, you can see this case: Difference between apk (.apk) and app bundle (.aab).

Google uses app bundle to generate and serve optimized APKs for each user’s device configuration, so they download only the code and resources they need to run your app. Therefore, users can get smaller and more optimized downloads.

It should be that VS removed some codes and resources while building the bundle, resulting in error.
